# NextJS: Axios or Fetch post and get method result wrong URL path api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js

here I want to make a post method on API but when I call the function it posts to the wrong path of API

here is my script for the post

```js
 //Creating Order
  const createOrder = async (data) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.API_ROOT}/api/orders` ||
          `${process.env.LOCAL_URL}/api/orders`,
        data
      );
      if (res.status === 201) {
        router.push(`/api/orders/${res.data._id}`);
        dispatch(reset());
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

I call that function when approve from Paypal and using the order button, but when I press the button
the URL API path change to something `${process.env.API_ROOT}/undefined/api/orders`  or `${process.env.LOCAL_URL}/undefined/api/orders` what cause this problem ?

[image]

but when im using something like its working

```js
//Creating Order
  const createOrder = async (data) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`/api/orders`,data);  <=====  its working
      if (res.status === 201) {
        router.push(`/api/orders/${res.data._id}`);
        dispatch(reset());
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the front-end part of the code and your `process.env.API_ROOT` resolves to undefined. However there is a way to use `process.env` variables in the frontend code, you just need to prefix them with `NEXT_PUBLIC` like this:

```
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LOCAL_URL
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ROOT
```

More info in the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser)

Comment: Thank you :) It help me I didn't know need to prefix with `NEXT_PUBLIC`